# Define return values type of subclasses without redefining parent implementation in python

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a base implementation of a tree that can contain trees and generic elements with a unique id, and I have some subclasses of tree which contains specific types of elements something like this:

```
class BaseTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self._my_elements_and_trees = []

    def append_element_or_tree(self, element_or_tree: Union["BaseTree", Any]) -> int:
        ...

    def iter_all_elements(self, is_recursive=True) -> Iterable[Any]:
        ...

    def iter_all_trees(self, is_recursive=True) -> Iterable["BaseTree"]:
        ...

    def get_element_from_id(self, element_id) -> Any:
        ...


class TreeOfMessages(BaseTree):
    """
    Tree containing instances of Messages
    """
    def do_something_with_messages(self):
        ...


class TreeOfMails(BaseTree):
    """
    Tree containing instances of Mails
    """

    def do_something_with_mails(self):
        ...
```

I would to declare my types such that when I use any of the parent methods (`iter_all_elements`, `iter_all_trees` or `get_element_from_id`) on any of my specific subclases I will get the specific objects (Messages or Mails) and their corresponding trees.

I know that it is possible to do the following:

```
class TreeOfMessages(BaseTree):
    """
    Tree containing instances of Messages
    """

    def get_element_from_id(self, element_id) -> Message:
        return super().get_element_from_id(element_id)
```

But I don't want to reimplement every method every time just to declare the types.

Comment: What happens if you do `some_tree_of_mails.append_element_or_tree(some_tree_of_messages)`? Is that a valid call? If it is, does the argument get treated as an element or a tree? How does it affect the behavior of `some_tree_of_mails.iter_all_elements()` and `some_tree_of_mails.iter_all_trees()`?

Comment: When appending elements the types are checked, so every tree inserted is of the same type as the current tree and every element is of the correct type, so when calling 'iter_all_elements' and 'iter_all_trees' I'm sure that I will get the correct types .

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html).

You can implement your BaseTree as a generic class with a specific type like so:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

ContainedType = TypeVar("ContainedType")

class BaseTree(Generic[ContainedType]):

    # Now just replace all parts where your current implementation uses "Any"
    # with "ContainedType", e.g.
    def get_element_from_id(self, element_id) -> ContainedType:
        ...
```

Then you can make your subclass acknowledge that it can only take messages by defining it like so:

```py
class MyMessage:
    pass

class TreeOfMessages(BaseTree[MyMessage]):
    pass
```

and the type checker will infer that TreeOfMessages uses MyMessage as the contained type for all calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to work for the elements, I would like to do the same for 'iter_all_trees' which return instances of the object itself, I don't know it there is a simple way to do so before python 3.11 (in python 3.11 there is a typing.Self which seems to work), I'm using 3.8.8

Comment: You can create another TypeVar with bound=BaseTree and annotate self and the return type with that